# Paypal Plus Germany | Cusom payment Button

Tags: paypal, paypal-plus

After long google searching and reading the documentation of Paypal Plus I didn't found any solution.

I'm trying to integrate Paypal Plus, I want to add a custom Payment on arrival to the List of Payment methods. Like in image

[image]

Is there any way to do it, is that possible?

Here is my Code:

```
<style>
.custom-payment {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  padding: 2px 20px;
  top: -29px;
}

.custom-payment:hover {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  cursor: pointer
}

div.checkMark {
  background-image: url(https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/ppplus/icons/checkmark.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 25px;
}
</style>

<div class="container" style="max-width: 600px">
  <div id="ppplus"></div>
  <div class="custom-payment d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between pt-3">
    <p>Pay on arrival</p>
    <div class="checkMark"></div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary text-white w-100 mb-4" onclick="ppp.doContinue()">Checkout</button>
</div>


<script>
  var ppp = PAYPAL.apps.PPP({
    "approvalUrl": "<?=$approval_url?>",
    "placeholder": "ppplus",
    "mode": "sandbox",
    "country": "DE",
    "buttonLocation": "outside",
    "preselection" : "paypal"
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Is your account enabled for PayPal Plus? I've heard that it's been deprecated. And what you want may require enabling. Contact PayPal for details, they'll point you to other resources if there's some other/newer solution.

Comment: Yes, it is enabled and it works fine, I just need to add a custom Button at the end of list and select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Pay on arrival" in the screenshot appears to be a customized [third party payment method](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/regional/de/how-to/3rd-party-payments/) in PayPal Plus DE.